# Is there a way to get a nice error report summary when running many jobs on DRMAA cluster?

Tags: snakemake

I need to run a snakemake pipeline on a DRMAA cluster with a total number of >2000 jobs.  When some of the jobs have failed, I would like to receive in the end an easy readable summary report, where only the failed jobs are listed instead of the whole job summary as given in the log.

Is there a way to achieve this without parsing the log file by myself?

These are the (incomplete) cluster options:

`jobs: 200
latency-wait: 5
keep-going: True
rerun-incomplete: True
restart-times: 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is another way than parsing the log file yourself, but I've done it several times with grep and I am happy with the results:

```
cat .snakemake/log/[TIME].snakemake.log | grep -B 3 -A 3 error
```

Of course you should change the `TIME` placeholder for whichever run you want to check.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. I had sth similar in mind. As jobs are re-run, there will be duplicates. So in my case a solution would be:
`cat .snakemake/log/[TIME].snakemake.log | grep -B 3 -A 3 error | grep output | sort | uniq > [new_log_file] `

Comment: However, my solution is not accurate, as jobs can fail (error message), get restarted, and be successful...therefore I asked for an internal snakemake solution which keeps track of the failed jobs.